# How to run Ansible with_fileglob in alpabetical order?

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, file-globs

I'm trying to build a system that will include tasks from a directory in alphabetical order.  Let's say I have the following files in a directory:

```
01-task.yml
02-task.yml
..
10-task.yml
```

I want ansible to include these tasks in order (01, 02, 03, etc).  In testing if fileglob is in order, I ran the following:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "File {{ item }}"
    with_fileglob: "<ansible directory>/testing/files/*"
```

And get the output in random order:

```
File <ansible directory>/testing/files/03-task.yml
File <ansible directory>/testing/files/05-task.yml
File <ansible directory>/testing/files/08-task.yml
File <ansible directory>/testing/files/09-task.yml
File <ansible directory>/testing/files/02-task.yml
File <ansible directory>/testing/files/10-task.yml
File <ansible directory>/testing/files/07-task.yml
File <ansible directory>/testing/files/01-task.yml
File <ansible directory>/testing/files/06-task.yml
File <ansible directory>/testing/files/04-task.yml
```

I'm struggling to come up with how I can sort the file globbing.  I'm hoping to avoid a task for set_fact in a loop to create an array, another task to sort, and another task to include the files.  Is there a more efficient way that I'm missing?

**EDIT: Thanks to Zeitounator I have a final working code of:**

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Test Import
    include_tasks: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ query('fileglob', \"<ansible directory>/testing/files/*\")|sort }}"
```

Each task file is just simply:

```
- debug: msg="This Is File [1-10]"
```

Which outputs in the correct order perfectly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using the new `loop` syntax and calling the lookup plugin directly, then sorting the result:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "File {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ query('fileglob', '<ansible directory>/testing/files/*') | sort }}"
```

References:

- [Ansible loop doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)
- [`fileglob` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html)
- [jinja2 builtin `sort` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#sort)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!